# Difference between -Wconversion between gcc and g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make GCC warn on passing too-wide types to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310108/can-i-make-gcc-warn-on-passing-too-wide-types-to-functions)

Consider the following test program:

```
static void func(int a)
{
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int b = 42;

    func(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with gcc:

```
lol@mac:~/projects$ gcc -Wconversion testit.c
testit.c: In function âmainâ:
testit.c:11: warning: passing argument 1 of âfuncâ as signed due to prototype
lol@mac:~/projects$
```

But, in g++ there is no warning!:

```
lol@mac:~/projects$ g++ -Wconversion testit.c
lol@mac:~/projects$
```

What is the reason for this and is there any way to get the same warning when compiling C++ code?

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for `-Wconversion`:

> Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

Seems that you'll need a sufficiently new version of GCC, too. I have version 4.0.1, and it doesn't recognize `-Wsign-conversion`.