# Make gcc warn implicit conversions

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make GCC warn on passing too-wide types to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310108/can-i-make-gcc-warn-on-passing-too-wide-types-to-functions)

Many times I cause bugs by passing a long to an integer function.

Can I make gcc warn me when I'm doing that?

Comment: You should really try searching for your answers before just posting them here. This is one quick google search away for your exact terms. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 21):

Try `-Wconversion`.

```
int fn(int);
int bar(long x) { return fn(x); }

gcc -c t.c  -Wconversion
t.c: In function ‘bar’:
t.c:3: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘long int’ may alter its value
```