# How can I have g++ print warnings for type casts to the arguments of functions?

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, compiler-warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make GCC warn on passing too-wide types to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310108/can-i-make-gcc-warn-on-passing-too-wide-types-to-functions)

Is there a way to make gcc or g++ produce a warning when I pass a signed int to a function that takes an unsigned int?

For instance:

```
int main(){
        char buf[8];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
                buf[i] = 'a';
        buf[6]='\0';
        strcat(buf, " ");
        strncat(buf, "happystacksmashingstring",-1 );
        return 0;

}
```

will cause stack smashing because strncat takes a size_t as its third argument, which is often an unsigned int. Yet, the command:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -W -Weffc++ -Wconversion test.c
```

which contains every warning flag I know, produces no errors or warnings at compile time, and a smashed stack at runtime.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -W -Wconversion test.c
```

*will* produce errors about the implicit conversions in contrast. Why doesn't the -Wconversion flag work properly with g++?

Comment: -Wsign-conversion. [In C++, ..., Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C ++ unless -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++)

Comment: @remi sorry, saw your comment too late. if you post an answer, I will delete mine

Comment: @RandolphCarter regarding the duplication: The other question involves autocasts, but of a rather different sort. I did not encounter it during my own searching for an answer to my question, and the answer it proposes (use -Wconversion) does not solve the problem in anycase.

Comment: Thanks for the -Wsign-conversion bit though! That's exactly what I seemed to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page of g++:

> Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless-Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.